# Error: Unexpected symbol in "setup_twitter_oauth"

Tags: r

I'm attempting to connect to twitter API in R using the API key, API secret, Access Token, and Access Token Secret. I have entered all necessary parts in the code and still get the error "unexpected symbol in "setup_twitter_oauth" but it does not specify which symbol is the error.

`setup_twitter_oauth(vvxvs8cKhZZF1OglYAoHdxE1k,2MfBAAUbuNqz2597rhchynfV2vO34J7SVb0c5x8RX7Wq77YzuM,228577878-NatdpafSCaUT8od7sN4c9Xt26LbctFrCxc9TGGYE,QFTwOitLz05qpqkQbY4yGSzn7TqHvhlV2NgjiBAfVJQf0)`

> Error: unexpected symbol in "setup_twitter_oauth(vvxvs8cKhZZF1OglYAoHdxE1k,2MfBAAUbuNqz2597rhchynfV2vO34J7SVb0c5x8RX7Wq77YzuM"

Comment: Did you just share your OAuth Key here?

Comment: I've regenerated the key so this is an old key for reference. I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my code.

Comment: You need to quote the oauth key, e.g. `"abc123..."`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Kevin Ushey, the parameters to this function need to by supplied as character strings:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(
   "vvxvs8cKhZZF1OglYAoHdxE1k", 
   "2MfBAAUbuNqz2597rhchynfV2vO34J7SVb0c5x8RX7Wq77YzuM", 
   "228577878-NatdpafSCaUT8od7sN4c9Xt26LbctFrCxc9TGGYE", 
   "QFTwOitLz05qpqkQbY4yGSzn7TqHvhlV2NgjiBAfVJQf0"
)
```

See the example section of `help("setup_twitter_oauth")`.